# Is it possible to use XPath to retrieve the value of a node based on a condition in a node that is deeper in the structure?

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<Data>
  <ID>ID 1</ID>
  <Type>
    <Text>Type 1</Text>
  </Type>
  <Value>Value 1</Value>
</Data>
<Data>
  <ID>ID 2</ID>
  <Type>
    <Text>Type 2</Text>
  </Type>
  <Value>Value 2</Value>
</Data>
```

If Text='Type 1', then I want to return the value of  within that  element (in this case I would return "Value 1").

I am able to use a predicate to retrieve the entire  element, but I'd like to find a way to only get  in order to avoid having to implement more logic after the XPath evaluation.

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
//Data/Value/text()[../../Type/Text/text()='Type 2']
```

Or maybe

```
//Data[Type/Text/text()='Type 2']/Value/text()
```

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking something along the lines of what you suggested, but wasn't certain about the syntax.  I'll apply these approaches and see if it works out.